# Is it possible to force display of a Google Doc outline with a url parameter?

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to force a view only Google Doc to load with the outline open using a url parameter?

This would be in addition to the display mode, e.g. view?rm=demo, and for use in an iframe.

It seems if a user is logged into their Google account and has hidden a document outline, that outline remain hidden upon reload until the user reopens it. On reload, I want to force the outline to display using a url parameter.

Comment: I do apologize for this, Please clarify your questions by adding in some specific details. Please add reproducible samples, screenshot, or even codes to have a better understanding of your question.